# EF5 Many to Many join table fluent API

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-5, poco

Do I have to create a POCO class to represent a join table in a many to many relationship?

This is my scenario:

```
public class Event 
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int OrganizerId { get; set; }
}

public class Person 
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Company 
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Both a Person or a Company can organize an event, I thought to create a join table like

```
Table Events_People
PersonId
OrganizerId


Table Events_Companies
CompanyId
OrganizerId
```

I know that should easy to do if I create two POCOs classes, like

```
public class EventPerson
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public Person PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

than with Fluent API something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
// PK
.HasKey(e => e.PersonId)
// FK
.HasMany(e => e.Events)
.WithRequired(e => e.PersonId);
```

Is there a way to avoid two POCOs and directly tell to the API to create the join table?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Many to Many with EF yes. The bigger question is that a good idea.  For example you may find you have issues with cascade delete if you do and you need or want that. If you end up with 2 required relationships to the same entity ( not necessarily your specific sample code) but more generically matched to your question, then you can get EF compile/runtime errors unless you use WillCascadeOnDelete(false).  Just in case people think, you can so therefore do it.   Becareful.:-)

**But you asked can you tell EF to create a Join**

Did you not see a join table generated by EF ?  I would have expected that. Im curious why not.

You can explicitly manage it:

```
HasMany(t => t.NavigationProperty1)
.WithMany(a => a.ReverseNavigationProperty)
.Map(c => c.ToTable("TheJoinTable"));



// rename keys as required, may not be required...
c.MapLeftKey("ColumnKeyName");
c.MapRightKey("ABetterName2");
```

BTW the example you suggest is exactly a pattern that is required to get around some CascadeOnDelete issues.

Comment: uhm .. right, I understood that I can get some problems, but how can I solve the problem in a different way? I thought that a join table was the best option

Comment: ps. i'm far to be a dba, but if I'm not wrong, in my scenario, I don't want to enable the cascade delete

Comment: Sorry, wasnt trying to confuse or rant.   I have been burnt be this issue and it take a while to rsolve with many tables and many relatioships.  Of course if not using cascade on delete all good :-D